# ReactJS Import react from 'react' issue

Tags: reactjs

I have some react code and have some stylecop issue with the below line complaining that "module has no default export".

```
import React from 'react'
```

I changed the above line to the below to fix it.

```
import * as React from 'react'
```

I have similar situation for the below import

```
import React, { Component, abc} from 'react'
```

I update import to below but it fails

```
import * as React, { Component, abc} from 'react'
```

What will be the real way to import  multiple items

Comment: Add  `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true` to your tsconfig.json

Comment: I already have allowSyntheticDefaultImports and esModuleInterop as true in config file but still stylecop throws errors. Our build and checkin process in tightly tied up with stylecop so tried to fix in the above way.

Comment: is there react in package.json file

Comment: Yes react exist and logic works fine but  style cop throws error instead of warning. This is blocking my build and release.

Answer (score 0):

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm -rf package-lock.json
npm i
```

try this command and check working or not,
proper way of importing react is

```
   import React from 'react'
```